# How to test client server connection over internet in one network?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, router, connection

I'm creating application which based on the client server communication over internet. So I have made server and put it on my computer(win 7, 64) and put client in virtual machine (xp, 32) test connection and it's working fine. That's mean that application work on network, but my question is how to test application that will work across internet? So I use in virtual machine, wireless and on computer have wire - connected to same router. At virtual machine have external ip adress 33.244.57.34, and on the computer external ip is 33.244.12.19 (this is not real ip's, but important is to see that first two numbers is same) is it mean that I already testing over internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, yes. Your local server should function the same remotely. The only difference is how you access it. For example, I have a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) (Linux Apache MySQL PHP) server running on my notebook. I use it to test my web projects, which I later move to a remote LAMP server hosted by a third party. The code runs the same in both environments.

Comment: So if I understand as well, that is like I'm really accessing each computer, like one network to another?

Comment: Not so much 'one network to another'. More so, 'client to server'. The functionality should be the same, whether it is local or on the internet.

Comment: Thnx ... man .... :)

Comment: You are welcome. If you run into any issues, just ask here on Superuser or on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), our sister site. :)